# In Laravel-5 localhost:8000 not working when in offline in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

With this command

```
php artisan serve
```

when my Ubuntu 14.04 is connected with network/online. It's ok. And shows

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

But when offline. Its show......

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
>   [Sun Dec 27 19:54:34 2015] PHP Warning:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in Unknown on line 0
>   [Sun Dec 27 19:54:34 2015] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

```
php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1
```